# Unconventional mouse movement request Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse

WINDOWS 10

I work in a Medical setting, supporting Radiology systems.  We have a strange request from one of our department heads due to the stay at home and working from home environment.

The current Radiology application is older, and does NOT run properly if monitors are vertically stacked in Windows display settings.  Unfortunately we have to set them up horizontally in Windows, even if their physical layout is different.

What he's requesting is similar to "wrap around" where if the mouse leaves the left edge it moves to the rightmost edge, and top to bottom similarly.  There are several options which can enable edge mouse wrapping, **Actual Multiple Monitors** and **Display Fusion** among them.

Because of the old application requiring horizontal and his physical layout not matching, the user is asking if we can somehow make the mouse to move from the top of monitor 1 to the bottom of monitor 3, and vice versa; without impacting the horizontal mouse movement.

Commercial software is not off the table, but so far I've found nothing which does this strange setup.  I thought about AHK and creating a script for using a hotkey to jump between the monitors, but that is not what the physician wants.

Comment: Normally I'd vote to close this as a 'product request'… **however**, in the current climate I'd say, we have a lot of expertise reading this stack - let's see if someone can find an answer to help out the medical profession in these desperate times !

Answer (score 1):

I didn't solve this one, the Radiologist did.  He looked deeper than the mouse controls in **AMM**, and found that he could force the application Windows to the correct screens.  He was able to use Windows 10's multiple monitor setup to place the monitors to match their physical layout, so mouse movement would be natural.  We're setting up a trigger control so he can hit one key combo to push all of the apps to the correct monitors.

Clever use of the application, OCD Radiologists often surprise us by using unexpected features of their programs.

Answer (score 0):

If the screen layout is not correctly configured, the cursor moves from one monitor screen to a second monitor through the opposite side of the screen. How to fix?
Open Control Panel \ All Control Panel Items \ Screen \ Screen Resolution
It is necessary to swap the screen 1 and 2 by simply dragging the mouse, we get.

If the monitors are located one above the other, when the monitors are upright with the cursor moving incorrectly Swap monitor 1 and 2

Comment: There is no `All Control Panel Items \ Screen` in my Windows 10. See https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21084-multiple-displays-change-settings-layout-windows-10-a.html#Part6

Answer (score 0):

[Continuous Mouse](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/continuous-mouse/9p6nts4k5425) should give you enough freedom to also solve your problem.

Here is an example setup where the mouse gets "Wrap around" on a single monitor:
[image: Here is an example configuration for the setup of "wrap around" on a single monitor]